# MemSql > workaround for SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

Tags: select, locking, singlestore

I am using MemSql as my DB and I need to have `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` functionality. However it is not supported in 6.5 version, which I am using. Is there any workaround for this problem?

My problem is as follows: multiple processes pick a single record (that has not been process yet) from the same table, do some job out of SQL code then do UPDATE for marking the record as processed. If I had a possibility to do `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` then I could lock the record for assuring that only one process can pick it.

As a workaround that I can think of is using some LockToken column and do something like

```
UPDATE Tbl SET LockToken = 'a_unique_token' WHERE LockToken IS NULL LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE LockToken = 'a_unique_token';
```

but in this case I get

> Error Code: 1749. Feature 'UPDATE...LIMIT must be constrained to a single partition' is not supported by MemSQL Distributed.

I could also do the job with `LOCK TABLES`, but according to [this](https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.5/lock-tables/) they are not supported as well.

Is there any workaround to this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your workaround is a good idea. One way you could workaround that error is to pick a specific row to lock instead of using LIMIT 1, like `UPDATE Tbl SET LockToken = 'a_unique_token' WHERE LockToken IS NULL and id = (select id from Tbl WHERE LockToken IS NULL limit 1)`. (Or you could use `(select min(id) from Tbl WHERE LockToken IS NULL)` or something similar to pick an id depending on what you want.) This should work well if you have an index on id.

Also, you could check out version 6.7 where select for update is now supported: https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.7/select/.

Comment: But is it safe to use SELECT in the conditional part of UPDATE? As far I understand, that part is not locking and two different processes can run the same SELECT script and the same value of ID.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, two processes would both read the same id, and the second would just block on doing the SET until after the first has already SET it, and therefore update zero rows. But you can detect that and retry, so this general strategy could still be helpful assuming most of the work is in the later part of the transaction and the initial update to set the lock is a minimal fraction of the overall work. You also can retrieve a random id instead of min/max, so that concurrent threads are unlikely to try to lock the same row.

Comment: I see. In that case I have two questions: 1. Is there any sql level possibility in MemSql to retrieve updated row count? 2. Is row locking for UPDATE is performed after the execution of the condition in the UPDATE statement? In this case it will lock a row after executing `LockTocken IS NULL AND ID = (...)` condition. Is that right?

Comment: 1. The updated rowcount is returned by the UPDATE statement - e.g. the MySQL CLI prints "Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1". You can also check whether anything is returned by the `SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE LockToken = 'a_unique_token'` query. 2. It locks while evaluating the filter and therefore only one UPDATE will see LockToken IS NULL, the others will see LockToken after the first update has changed it. You can observe this behavior by running `begin; UPDATE Tbl ...` in one session, then `UPDATE TBL ...` in another session, then `commit` the first.

Comment: Thanks. I try to figure out one question. If from each thread I am updating LockToken for a row with the same ID and in the same script I am selecting the same row for using it in C++ code, couldn't be any scenario, when one UPDATE will override another's LockToken? In that case in my C++ code I will work with a record, which has been updated after when I read is from DB.

Comment: No, that's what I described above where the LockToken IS NULL filter is evaluated atomically with changing the value of LockToken. The update holds a lock on the row for the duration of that access.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and inform you about the results. Also, can a functionality similar to LOCK TABLES gained with `UPDATE Tbl SET LockToken=LockToken;` kind of script?

Comment: Yes, that would let you lock all the rows of the table. It's a bit different because it won't prevent inserts, but that isn't necessary for what you described.

Comment: I see. And one more question about conditions evaluation sequence. As far as I read on the internet SQL engine itself decides in which sequence to evaluate conditions in `WHERE` clause. So, if I have defined LockToken column with `KEY (LockToken) USING HASH` command, is it guaranteed that `id = (select min(id) from Tbl WHERE LockToken IS NULL)` will be evaluated first and then only after that `LockToken IS NULL` will be evaluated in `WHERE` of `UPDATE`. Could that be dependent on MemSql version?

Comment: The subselect `(select min(id) from Tbl WHERE LockToken IS NULL)` will be evaluated first, and then both the `LockToken IS NULL` and `id = ...` filters get evaluated effectively simultaneously. If you have defined a hash index on LockToken then you should probably also define a hash index on id, or you could define both as non-hash. MemSQL should use the index on `id` to efficiently seek to the row. If `id` is defined as a primary or unique key then memsql will also prefer it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `ID` is defined as primary key. Can I be sure that described behavior is the same for all versions of MemSQL?

Comment: Yes it should be the same.

Comment: What other versions are you potentially using? If you upgrade to 6.7 you can use SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Comment: Other versions that can be used are older versions such as MemSQL 6.0. Also I may use the same code for MySQL.